# Ошибка в установке всех зависимостей в проекте php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Скачал с github проект, пытаюсь загрузить все зависимости, чтобы все работало и закинуть на сервер.
Испытываю неимоверные трудности, так как получаю постоянно ошибки. Еще сверху недостаток опыта в php. Короче боль

- Не хочет скачиваться папка `/vendor` в корень проекта при установке `composer`
- Не работают команды `artisan`, хотя сам файл есть
- Не работают команды `composer`

Я уже круглые сутки не могу разобраться с данными проблемами, гугл не помогает.
Был бы очень признателен, если бы кто-то выделил мне время на созвон в дискорде допустим и помог мне разобраться со всеми ошибками(естественно не за простое "спасибо")

Comment: Вот мой дискорд - bluepuper#0605
Или телеграм - bluepuper

Comment: а какие ошибки то?

Comment: "Не хочет скачиваться папка /vendor ..." крайне подробное описание проблемы. Консоль, конечно, никаких ошибок не выдаёт

Answer (score 0):

Установите composer с официального сайта
https://getcomposer.org
Потом сделаете composer install в вашем проекте